Unity - some materials are sill pink after migrating to HDRP
I have upgraded to HDRP some materials are still pink. Ive tried to upgrade them one by one but nothing works. They are pink also it I put them into brad new HDRP project. 

then they arent hdrp compatible...

So its possible that some materials wont work in HDRP no matter what I do?

It's not about the materials but rather the shaders .. but yeah you can not convert them all. Some are simply not compatible you can try and manually switch your materials to use an HDRP shader that fulfills your needs

Your screenshot shows that you are using Legacy shaders. Legacy shaders are only compatible with the built-in render pipeline and are not HDRP or URP compatible. Also, they are low-quality by today's standards; why would you want to use old, low-quality shaders in a High-Definition Render Pipeline project?
